# Laravel 5 and Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

Hi I have one question and here it is.
Can we share the session between `laravel4` and `laravel5` code on a single domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Database sessions you are able to do this, I'm not sure how nicely it will play with other session drivers.